# Return types of Action Creators in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-promise-middleware

I am new to Redux structure.. So far, i have developed an app in which we can render tables details from a list. So one of my action creator is selectTable as below:

```
export function selectTable(table) {
  var APP = table.app;
  var TABLE = table.name;
  var url = `http://10.61.23.3:4005/v1/tables/find-by-app-and-name/${APP}/${TABLE}`;
const req = Axios.get(url);
  return {
    type: 'TABLE_SELECTED',
    items: table,
    payload: req

  }

}
```

Since i am using redux promise middleware , i am catching the action 'TABLE_SELECTED_FULFILLED' in my reducer and tried to access items part of the action (items: table,) but it is giving undefined..so all i got in my reducer is action.type and payload.. 
So can someone kindly help .. how can i access that table details or items part from my action creator into my reducer..
Thank you.

Comment: if you have created action then you have to call actionAlias.actionmethod and pass your object there it self refer this http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#async-action-creators

Comment: sorry, I didnt get that.. Like I have a working flow of my app but i just require additional info.. that is the items or table details and i am unable to pass it to reducers..so how exactly can I do that?